# Blender crashes when iterating over collection.all_objects

Tags: python, keyframes

When I try to set a keyframe for every object in a collection with the script below, blender immediately crashes. I'm running this on a host-collection with 30 objects in it, so I don't think this should be such a memory hungry operation.

Does anybody have an idea why this could be happening?

```
def hideObj(obj, kf):
    obj.hide_viewport = True
    obj.hide_render = True
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path = "hide_viewport", frame = kf)
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path = "hide_render", frame = kf)
   
for obj in bpy.data.collections["HOST"].all_objects:
    hideObj(obj, 0)
```

Here's the error log

```
> I0315 18:37:41.637778  7144 device.cpp:45] CUEW initialization
> succeeded I0315 18:37:41.650597  7144 device.cpp:47] Found precompiled
> kernels I0315 18:37:41.667937  7144 device.cpp:68] HIPEW
> initialization failed: Error opening HIP dynamic library Error   :
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION Address : 0x00007FF6280520FA Module  :
> blender.exe Thread  : 00001be8 Switching to fully guarded memory
> allocator. Blender 3.0.0 Build: 2021-12-03 00:44:02 Windows release
```

Comment: "hide_viewport" property cannot be animated so that line in your code is not doing anything but I don't know if it is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for obj in bpy.data.collections["Host"].all_objects:
    
    if obj.type == "Mesh":
        hideObj(obj, 0)
```

because i could reproduce your crash if a camera is in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

"hide_viewport" can definitely be animated. The problem apparently is a documented gotcha.
Answer from the blender dev team:

> This is, unfortunately, a documented problem:
> https://docs.blender.org/api/master/info_gotcha.html#unfortunate-corner-cases
>
> Modifying the hide_viewport or hide_render properties on an object
> will re-construct the collection object list. As such you are
> enumerating over a list that might change which isn't permitted.

I ended up putting all objects into a dictionary and that solved the problem.

```
hostObjs = {}
for obj in host.all_objects:
    hostObjs[obj.name] = obj
```